# Class method masquerading as field

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class named ResourceBin.

```
class ResourceBin
{
    public:
        ResourceBin();
        virtual ~ResourceBin();
        int getResource(Resources resource) const;
        void setResource(Resources resource, int amount);
        int addResource(Resources resource, int amount);
        unsigned int getMax(Resources resource) const;
        void setMax(Resources resource, unsigned int amount);
        bool simulateAddResource(Resources resource, int amount) const;
        bool maxOn = true;
        ResourceBin operator+(const ResourceBin& bin);
    protected:
        int resources[2];
        unsigned int maxamount[2];
        unsigned int getIndex(Resources resource) const;
    private:
};

typedef ResourceBin ResourceList;
```

I would like to make sure that if MaxOn is equal to true that none of my resource values (stored in resources) is greater than it's max amount.  Is there any way that I can make a method run anytime that maxOn is changed or set?

Comment: Why can't you just have a method for setting `maxOn`?  You could put your checking code in that call.

Comment: You can make maxOn your own class instance instead of bool, and override assignment operator for that class... you really don't want to go there.

Comment: I could make a method for setting it. Just seemed like it would be better suited to a field. If that way away from standard practice, I could just make a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: practically no. You have to make `maxOn` a private class member, and provide its own getter and setter method.

The reason for the "practically" qualifier is that it's possible to build a house of cards which will result in a statement of the form:

```
pointerToResourceBin->maxOn=true;
```

execute a class method. `maxOn` wouldn't be an ordinary `bool`, but a custom class, with an `operator=` and an `operator bool()`, making it act like a `bool` value, but the `operator=` would update the flag, and, using a number of approaches, execute a method in its parent class to validate the required constraint.

It's possible, and it's quite a bit of work. But don't do that. It's ugly. Just replace `maxOn` with a getter and a setter.